# Use Mvc 2 with ninject 2 and NHibernate - Get SessionFactory

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, ninject

I'm trying to combine Mvc2 with Ninject and NHibernate, and found a guide here:
http://damianm.com/tech/nhibernate-mvc-and-ninject/

The problem is that he use Ninject 1. So i have to convert it, and I'm almost succesfull, but i still got one problem:

Im not sure how to convert the "context.Kernel.Get" here:

```
protected override ISession CreateInstance(IContext context)
{
   var sessionFactory = context.Kernel.Get<ISessionFactory>();
   return sessionFactory.OpenSession();
}
```

If you have betters ways to integrate these three libraries, please tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm doing essentially the same thing in my project, however I'm not using a provider for ISession.  here's my binding:

```
        Bind<ISessionFactory>()
            .ToProvider<SessionFactoryBuilder>()
            .InSingletonScope();

        Bind<ISession>()
            .ToMethod( context => context.Kernel.Get<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession() )
            .InRequestScope();
```

Comment: But I still get: 'Ninject.IKernel' does not contain a definition for 'Get' and no extension method 'Get' accepting a first argument of type 'Ninject.IKernel' could be found. Which version are u using?

Comment: ah.  the 'Get' methods are extension methods.  add a `using Ninject;`